# How to create a one-to-many relationship for a fact table

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, dimensional-modeling

If I have a fact table for various NFL Teams. One of the relationship is between a `Player` and a `Team`. A team contains many players. If the fact table is based on the `Season+Team` how would I add a one-to-many key from the `player` to the `fact` table? The below is what I currently have:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you wouldn't add a one-to-many key from the player to the fact table. Instead you would add a bridge table between the Team Dim and the Player Dim.

Longer Answer/Background...

When you design a fact table you need to define its grain i.e. which dimensions uniquely identify each record in the fact. Once you have defined this grain you should never make any changes to the design that will change the grain (unless you've realised that the initial grain was wrong and you need to re-define your fact table from scratch.

You've defined your fact table grain as Season+Team and therefore you cannot add Player to your fact table as this would change the grain.

If you do add a bridge table then it will allow you to report on your fact by player but it also introduces a risk to your reporting that you need to be aware of. For example, you can show wins per year per player but you can't aggregate up these results as your wins would be double counted (every player in the same team is effectively claiming those same wins)

Comment: I like your explanation, Nick! Note from my side: many-to-many bridge table between teams and players may significantly grow because of player changes their teams etc. On cube side using many-to-many relation starts affecting performance with >1M rows in a bridge table. I would also suggest to eliminate [Season] and use [Date] dimension instead. Because all info from [Season] table can be queried from [fact]. Also player can possibly switch teams in the middle of the year. So Teams_Players to be a bridge between Teams and Players and Date instead of Season.

Comment: @AlexPeshik If it was me designing this then I would start at a lower level: probably have player/game as my base fact and have player/team as a hierarchy. You can then build up separate  aggregate fact tables from both the team and player perspective - rather than trying to combine the two at the season level in a single fact - as you say this gets complicated with M:M joins and performance implications plus you start to need SCD2 on both the dimensions and bridges which can get interesting!